# Prevent sign in when user is already signed in - Google Sign-In JavaScript

Tags: google-signin

I implemented [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) and used their [`signin2.render()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#ui-elements) method to render a button for signing in.

I noticed that the button updates automatically. It displays "Signed in with Google" or "Sign in with Google" which is nice.

However, when you're "signed in" the button is still active and will sign you in again if you click it.

I tried to remove the event listener, but have been successful so far:
[image]

Is there any way to prevent or override this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signin2.render()` is a handy function to display "Sign in" button and let user sign in with least effort. But if you want to do further with Google Sign-in like sign out etc, this isn't the best way to go.

I would recommend to follow the path explained here as "a custom graphic button".

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#building_a_button_with_a_custom_graphic

This way, you can show whatever label on the button or let the user sign out with the same button etc.
You will need to learn Google Sign-in's JavaScript APIs but this works far more flexible.